# Archimedean property and Well-Ordering Principle

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[Bit from book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apOv3.jpg)

Definitely me missing something easy here but say I take $a=4$ and $b=9$ then wouldn’t the least element be $b-ma=1$ where $m=2$ and how could  $b-(m+1)a$ also lie in $S$ because wouldn’t this be $9-(3)4=-3$? I’m just not seeing why the notice of $b-(m+1)a$ comes about.
Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind the context: we're assuming for contradiction that $\mathbb{N}$ is non-Archimedean, so $a$ and $b$ are taken to be positive integers such that $an<b$ for every positive integer $n$.

Answer (score 1):

What you have noticed is the contradiction which is used in the proof.

The assumption was that all $b-ma$ are positive. This is false as proved in the book and as is illustrated by your example.

Answer (score 0):

That's the point: if the Archimedean property fails for two positive integers $a$ and $b$, then the members of $S = \{ b - na \mid \mbox{$n$ is a positive integer}\}$ would all be positive, but that can't happen.  In particular, it doesn't happen for $a = 4$ and $b = 9$, as your calculations show.

If you know about division, then you know that for any positive integers $a$ and $b$, there exist non-negative integers $q$ and $r$ such that $0 \le r < a$ and
$$
b = qa + r
$$
and then you can take $n = q + 1$ to give an $n$ such that $na > b$. The proof given in the book avoids knowledge of division (and could be used to develop the theory of division).